# Add more disk space to partition (11.10)

Tags: 11.10, gnome, disk-usage

Ubuntu is complaining that it's running out of space, and indeed, `df` yields:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0             17G   15G  462M  98% /
/dev/sda2             385G   18G  368G   5% /host
```

So apparently I only have 17 gigs available on my ubuntu installation.  When I run `gparted`, I see a `/dev/sda2` and a `/dev/sda1` both well over 100G.  My computer should have something like 600G available.

Is there any way I can add more disk space to `/dev/loop0`, whatever that is?  Please explain to me as if I were a child.

I also don't have an ubuntu CD .. I installed it with wubi.  I'm hoping I can just do this straight from the OS, but I understand I may have to do it from the BIOS.  I have read something like

> Boot from the CD and use `gparts`

That doesn't mean anything to me, so if that's what I need to do, please explain how to do that specifically.

Answer (score 1):

From your filesystem structure it seems like you've installed Ubuntu as a guest OS on your Windows using Wubi. When you installed it you specified 17G as the size of the virtual disk that Ubuntu can use - This is your /dev/loop0.
The /dev/sda2 is the disk of your Windows partition and therefore can not be resized to move space from it to the Ubuntu partition.

However, there is still a way to resize the virtual disk size of Wubi and is described in the [WubiGuide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_do_I_resize_the_virtual_disks.3F) which references to a simple script the you can download and execute. Detailed instructions are inside that guide.